# Ruby refinements and hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinements

I'm trying to use ruby refinements to apply rails hooks.

I want to avoid monkey patching. When monkey patching it would work as such

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  after_find do 
     # do something with 
     my_method
  end

  def my_method
    # something useful
  end
end
```

I've been able to have the class method by doing something like such:

```
module ActiveRecordRefinements
  refine ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class do
    def my_method
     #something cool
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't run the hook. I tried using `self.used(klass)` but don't seem to be able to get the syntax just right.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to call `#singleton_class` on `ActiveRecord::Base` since refinements are singletons.

Comment: I'm trying to add to the DSL of AR. Something like

```
class Foo < AR::Base
   using ActiveRecordRefinements
   my_method :my_stuff
end
```
Since I'm not adding methods to an object (well, a singleton object), I found that I did need the singleton_class

Comment: There's a fine line between monkey patching and dependency injection. Normally monkey patching is defined as redefining core behaviour in a manner that's not necessarily going to work with future versions of the core. A cleaner dependency injection model tries to avoid conflict and maintain a minimal footprint.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason you're not using ActiveSupport Callbacks? 
Take a look here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html